# In JSF how to hide resultBean until doAction executed?

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am adding a web service into JSF page. The page should take some input and give some output after the submit button clicked. 
My problem is that before the button clicked there is a empty from displayed on the page. I want know how to hide it if the form is empty.

The following is my jsp code

```
    <h:form styleClass="form" id="form1">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Number:</td>
                    <td><h:inputText styleClass="inputText" id="trainNumber1"
                        value="#{xxx_PortType_Display.paramBean.Request.Number}">
                    </h:inputText></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hx:commandExButton id="buttonDoAction1" styleClass="commandExButton"
            type="submit" value="Submit"
            action="#{xxx_PortType_Display.doAction}">
        </hx:commandExButton>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Result:</td>
                    <td><h:outputText styleClass="outputText" id="quotaCount1"
                        value="#{xxx_PortType_Display.resultBean.result}">
                    </h:outputText></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </h:form>
```

I don't want to “Result:” displayed before the doAction execute/button clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty xxx_PortType_Display.resultBean.result}">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Result:</td>
                <td><h:outputText styleClass="outputText" id="quotaCount1"
                    value="#{xxx_PortType_Display.resultBean.result}">
                </h:outputText></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Output result: via outputText and use rendered attribute on it.
Even better, put whole part with result into some component and set rendered on that component.